# How to correctly apply generic type definition for generic static methods?

Tags: typescript, generics, static-methods

I have the following base and derived classes.

```
class GenericBase<T = any> {
  static method(id: any) {
    console.log(`${id}: ${this.name}#method`);
  }
  public someProp!: T;
}

class DerivedGeneric extends GenericBase<Date> {}
```

I am looking for a way to correctly apply type definitions that will allow me to call the static method. Below is what I have tried so far.

```
const t1: typeof GenericBase = DerivedGeneric;
t1.method("t1");

type Type<T> = new (...arg: any[]) => T;
const t2: Type<GenericBase> = DerivedGeneric;
t2.method("t2");
```

For the first one (`t1`), TypeScript shows following error

```
Type 'typeof DerivedGeneric' is not assignable to type 'typeof GenericBase'.
  Type 'DerivedGeneric' is not assignable to type 'GenericBase'.
    Types of property 'someProp' are incompatible.
      Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

For the second one it shows the following error.

```
Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Type>'.
```

Naturally, the following works without any compile time error ...

```
const t3: Function = DerivedGeneric;
(t3 as typeof DerivedGeneric).method("t3");
```

... and so does the following, but now we have a runtime error.

```
const t4: Function = () => {};
(t4 as typeof DerivedGeneric).method("t4");
```

Without generics, the first approach (`typeof *Base*`) works quite well. You can check that from this [playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GgFsEsALAewBMAKPKgLmjADsBPAShXQ2mApYQKIBADoQFAOY0ABgBJk9AL5MF5PBFEswJJQGIS5ajI4BuHkp4AHAK4AjEAUwUSABQBOFKwEIm2d3gskuaWqKCQMAAiCAEAbghU0AgAHlgILFQw8BBIyKH8gljQWExYbFYIFABmcIjQALzQ0XEJ5liihpS0AERY3WaoqAD0AFTQALSTU9MzU9AjQ4PhUNAA4ukxBNkIADwAKg3M7AB83BjYuE6d1HSMR5xnvAVCIuJSsgrKqsjqmtq6BlIXRM5gwlgwtgcTiEbk8PiYexCS3AK2aeHiVHWLE2hBSaQyMCxOO2O0iuAQpzySwE2GKAEZSuVKjUiQFgNtDmiMayCG06R0gTdenT+uZUGUKtA9kz9qdGtiAO7QGiiVVgdySJisNgAbQAulx6qdEWEaUUsAAmBEynnsxBypqbbkbNltC0Cow9S2i6mFYoAZiYADEbCxgPgBJynQlbeYaFh-cwYBLmY6WpiXQQOB6ujRev6faa-VgACzB0PhvCRxo0Q2UpRx0tJ4pM6pp9ExzPAbPXL0ln1AA). Obviously, all approaches (except `t4`) work in runtime, and only the compile time errors are bugging me.

Is there any way to correct the typings with the generics?

**Edit:**
[Link to playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GgFsEsALAewBMAKPKgLmjADsBPAShXQ2mApYQKIBADoQFAOY0ABgBJk9AL5MF5PBFEswJJQGIS5ajI4BuHkp4AHAK4AjEAUwUSABQBOFKwEIm2d3gskuaWqKCQMAAiCAEAbghU0AgAHlgILFQw8BBIyKH8gljQWExYbFYIFABmcIjQALzQ0XEJ5liihpS0AERY3WaoqAD0AFTQALSTU9MzU9AjQ4PhUNAA4ukxBNkIADwAKg3M7AB83BjYuE6d1HSMR5xnvAVCIuJSsgrKqsjqmtq6BlIXRM5gwlgwtgcTiEbk8PiYe1BfAE-hswCwFHcNC4aF4yMEwjEEmk3XWLE2wG2fAx7n6SMs+XAK2aeHiVDJFKSqXSmTWGwClMQO0iuAQp1x+NR6Mx2Me5xsFSxAzxz0JbxJLLZHIF1MxdIsqFCZQq0D25V2e1OjXJAHdoDRRI6wO5JExWGwANoAXS49VOiNQxqQVRsLEIjVcBAA1jsg9U+eSBdsADTQKMINjxuM1bVbRCnABkPDNFR2ucFOWO5jCKKKVQAjEwQ2HDpqEuXzA2OkCbt0G-rnkUKHYAFaHW3QBvY6tDIaSopYRvFc3x8tUxpt9n8gjmWfFevdow9Rf64ZzwfFABMCPNZe3FbFrc2Wvvu7nWEvh66NF6l9Pe4vLAAGYmAAMVDdE8AEJ8Wi3RMdzPe1gOYGBsyaZ923vDgv17YD-3PWtigAFjAiD8GgxpZT9FAlDfJCiJQ5cKnjTdy2w65jyI-UgA) with the following type.

```
type Type<T> = new (...arg: any[]) => T;
type func = Pick<typeof GenericBase, keyof typeof GenericBase> & Type<GenericBase>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since the base class has a generic type parameter it's constructor is a generic constructor. This would be what the constructor signature would look like:

```
const t3 : new <T>(...arg: any[]) => GenericBase<T> = GenericBase
```

This is why when you try to assign `DerivedGeneric` to `typeof GenericBase` you can't, because `DerivedGeneric` does not have such a generic constructor.

If you just want a type that represents the statics of the class you can use `Pick` to get rid of the generic constructor signature from `typeof GenericBase`:

```
const t1: Pick<typeof GenericBase, keyof typeof GenericBase> = DerivedGeneric; // OK
t1.method("t1");
```

You can also create an intersection of a constructor returns `GenericBase<any>` and the static members.

```
type Type<T> =  new (...args: unknown[]) => T;
const t1: Type<GenericBase> & Pick<typeof GenericBase, keyof typeof GenericBase>  = DerivedGeneric;
t1.method("t1");
new t1()
```

Note: it will not work with `...args: any[]`, `any` is a bit special not sure how that plays into this, but `unknown` should be preferred anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Just another follow up question. What do you think about `type Type<T> = new (...arg: any[]) => T; type func = Pick<typeof GenericBase, keyof typeof GenericBase> & Type<GenericBase>;`? Though playground shows error, it works on my machine :)

Comment: @SayanPal I actually tried that myself, and got an error.. not sure why I would have expected it to work as a solution for having both the statics and a non generic constructor, but for some reason it errors out ..

Comment: Updated the question with the link to playground.

Comment: @SayanPal added a version that adds the constructor back in